# How to expand the nodes by default on page load

Tags: javascript, html

i have used the following code.Now i want to expand all the nodes by default on page load.can anyone suggest me how to do it

```js
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var classList = parent.classList;
        if(classList.contains("open")) {
            classList.remove('open');
            var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
            for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
            }
        } else {
            classList.add('open');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}

ul.tree li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tree li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.tree li.open > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.tree li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tree li a:before {
    height: 1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: .2em;
}

ul.tree li > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '+';
}

ul.tree li.open > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '-';
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree">
  <li ><a href="#">Part 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Part 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want them open by default... so add `class="open"` to your `li` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the class name of `open` to your list items `<li>` tag that you wish to expand by default. Simple find done by reading the source code which leads me to believe you don't really understand how the source code you're using works...

```js
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
  tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var parent = e.target.parentElement;
    var classList = parent.classList;
    if (classList.contains("open")) {
      classList.remove('open');
      var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
      for (var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++) {
        opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
      }
    } else {
      classList.add('open');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

ul.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul.tree li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.tree li.open>ul {
  display: block;
}

ul.tree li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tree li a:before {
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  font-size: .8em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: .2em;
}

ul.tree li>a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '+';
}

ul.tree li.open>a:not(:last-child):before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree">
  <li class="open"><a href="#">Part 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="open"><a href="#">Part 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="open"><a href="#">Part 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item C</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item D</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open"><a href="#">Item E</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> **Update**

As **AVI** has suggested: "you can also write something like tree[i].click(); before applying the event listener if you want that programmatically."

```
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
  tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var parent = e.target.parentElement;
    var classList = parent.classList;
    if (classList.contains("open")) {
      classList.remove('open');
      var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
      for (var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++) {
        opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
      }
    } else {
      classList.add('open');
    }
  });
  tree[i].click();
}
```

Comment: you can also write something like tree[i].click(); before  applying the event listener if you want that programmatically.

Comment: @avi, I tried that but it didn't work for me but I have just found out why :p I kept putting it in the wrong loop! hehe! I will add the suggestion.

Comment: @avi I have added it into my answer, feel free to edit my answer by adding in your jsfiddle example (Credit to avi for the jsfiddle).